# Is $S=\{(1,t)\mid t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My professor introduced subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ today and I don't think I understand them very well.

He posed this question as an example:

> Is the set $S=\{(1,t)\mid t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

He said that it wasn't. Could anyone elaborate as to why it isn't?

Can I simply say that the zero vector, $\vec{0}=(0,0)$ can never equal $(1,t)$ and be done with it?

Comment: yes. That suffices. No zero, no vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that some set is a subspace, you must show two things:

1. You can pick any two vectors in the set, add them together, and the result is in the set.
2. You can pick any vector in the set, multiply it by any scalar, and the result is in the set.

The easiest check is for the $\vec{0}$ to be in the set.  Why?  If it isn't in the set, then multiplying by zero (a scalar) results in a vector *not* in the set!  (Violation of condition 2.)

So, in short, you're perfectly right. `;)`

Comment: This is not sufficient. You must also check the subset is nonempty. Customarily, this is done by checking that $\vec 0$ is in it. The argument @anorton gives assumes there's some vector there to start with. :)

Answer (score 1):

YOU are right. **Every vector space must have a zero.** However set $S$ is not a vector subspace, though it is a topology subspace.